# How can I determine the light level of a block with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to build a set of command blocks that will automatically place a torch at the foot of a player (or entity) when the light level falls below a certain threshold.  So basically I need to be able to determine the light level at a player using command blocks.

I've looked the some of the wiki pages on NBT data to see if the light level is stored with the block, so I could do something like `/execute @p ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:air 0 {dataTagForLight:3b}`, but there doesn't seem to be any such data tag.

I've considered spawning a daylight detector, but I have a feeling it won't do what I want it to do while in caves, since as far as I can tell, in the primary mode, it's only affected by sunlight.  Plus there's other issue with the plan, and it just feels like a kludge.

So, is there a way to determine the light level of a given block?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This method is also a fairly bad kludge and a bit impractical, but it should be able to detect block light as well as sunlight.

There are a few of processes that only occur at certain light levels, sunlight or not:

```
Event            || Light Level
================================
Snow/ice melt    || >=12
Mushrooms uproot || >=13
Flowers uproot   || <=7
Plants grow      || <=9
```

With a very high `/gamerule randomTickSpeed`, these processes can happen almost immediately. Obvious disadvantage here is that the gamerule will also effect the processes throughout the entire world.

Different mobs also have different spawning light levels:

```
Mob              || Light Level
================================
Bats             || <=3
Most hostiles    || <=7
Blaze/silverfish || <=11
Most passives    || >=9
```

You can also create custom mob spawners will spawn a mob every tick by changing its `MinSpawnDelay` and `MaxSpawnDelay`.

Using either of these methods (or both), what you'd need to do is something like:

1. Clone blocks around the block/player to a specific area
2. Set the block/spawner in the middle of the newly cloned area
3. Wait a few ticks
4. Test if a mob has spawned, or a process occurred

You could also have the mob spawner (minecart) or test block at the actual player's location, rather than cloning it first, which would reduce lag a lot but cause the player to see flickering mobs/blocks.

Comment: Yeah, the idea is to run this on a repeating command block, and if I think using a daylight sensor is a bit of a kludge, what does that make this?

Comment: Also, this really only tests an area, not a particular block.

Comment: @MBraedley It does test a particular block; the one that you're setting to wheat/ice/whatever. The rest of the area is only cloned as to get the same light level at that block. It is a bad kludge, as I say in the answer, but works for blocklight which a daylight sensor does not. AFAIK it's the only real way of doing it.